# Do not move content when ad appears

Tags: feature-request, site-ads

Currently, when I open a question that has an ad, there is a delay between the content to show up and the ad (banner between the title and the content) to show up.

When the ad appears, it moves all content down, to create space for the ad.

This post is a feature request to change this behavior. Basically, I would prefer the content to not be moved when the ad appears, and instead just have it pre-compute the required space of the ad and have the content be already at the correct place when the ad is shown.

A not ideal but probably quicker alternative is to have a slow transition between `no ad` to `an ad`, so that at least I can follow the text as it moves.

I understand that I am asking to not be bothered by an ad when reading questions, but long gone are the days where ads were expected to be placed on top of the content in an effort for the reader to be forced to read it. 
At most, it just makes the content and the ad less appealing altogether. I will still glance at the ad when reading the content, even without having it replace the content that I am reading.

Comment: #metoo for the "Job recommendations" banner on my account's activity page. It always loads late, and always pops up in exactly the spot where the various activity tabs used to be, so I often click on the banner instead of the tab I wanted to click on.

Comment: 100% support this request. Often times spammers put the spam link at the end of the post, and often times the ad moves the mouse pointer from the "flag" link to the spam link conveniently...

Comment: This behaviour is being used by _questionable_ sites to trick people into clicking them. Whether intended or not, this kind of behaviour gives me the chills, _brrrrrr_

Comment: Can't they do a grey box placeholder that reserves the correct amount of space?

Comment: I feel like ad providers are taking advantage of the dynamic nature of browsers, and deliberately *not* providing ad size, specifically so there can't be placeholders created for them.  Too many people are wise to ad antics, so now they need to be tricked into clicking on them.

Comment: @fbueckert: Space still has to be budgeted somehow. Probably by the site. Otherwise ads could be put in spaces that are too small to hold them.

Comment: This is one of the major reasons I use an Adblocker. I am happy to look at ads on white listed sites, however, I hate it when displaying ads results in dynamically changing the layout. It is one of the reasons SO is no longer white listed in my Adblocker

Comment: Plus on touchscreen devices with slow connections it's super annoying when content moves around. Those "ARGH I wanted to read that hot network question, now I'm on IBM's web site? <back> and now the hnq list has refreshed, oh well" moments that somehow end up taking a full 45 seconds kinda stink.

Comment: "This behaviour is being used by questionable sites to trick people into clicking them."... precisely @Roberrrt!

Comment: @fbueckert Those kinds of clicks are actually bad for advertisers, because they have to pay for all the false clicks, which are probably less likely to generate revenue for them. Eventually, what's bad for advertisers is also bad for ad networks.